# Web Audio API, capture the audio being played in a tab with no access to the last node

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a web app which streams to the output and plays audio on the speaker. I don't have access to the last node in the audio context because that's a third party library I don't wanna touch.

Is there a way to capture the data being played on the `audioContext.destination` ?

Comment: It's insane nobody has answered this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `audioContext.destination`, then take a look at https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioDestinationNode; the destination has an output so you could conceivably connect that to something else to capture audio data.

However, I'm not sure any browser has implemented this.

Comment: the mozilla doc says it has no outputs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioDestinationNode

Comment: The mozilla doc is not normative.  The actual WebAudio spec is. Who ya gonna believe?